# STORE command in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

> Suppose I am storing the data in a file named abc in hdfs using a pig
>   script test.pig.
>
> I am running the 20 instances of the same code in parallel by passing parameter to the pig script.

```
 pig -param "RANGE= a > 100 AND a < 4000" -f test.pig
 pig -param "RANGE= a > 4001 AND a < 10000" -f test.pig
```

Is it possible to store the data in the same file abc .
        Since I am running all the 20 instances in parallel I am getting an error that the file already exists in hdfs.
    So can i override it?

Comment: If you are passing the parameter to the pig script, can you try passing the out file names also or just the file name indexes which will be appended to the static file name.

Comment: @user131990 : Can we have subfolders inside abc directory based on range ? eg : abc/100 ....abc/10000 ?

Comment: Reading from the same file should be possible. Did you make sure that each invocation of the script writes its output to a separate folder?

Comment: @MuraliRao Yes we can have subfolders inside the abc directory.If we follow the above approach how to merge the files from the various subdirectory into a single file?

Comment: @LiMuBei I am trying to write all the output in a single folder and my question is regarding that only.If its possible and if not what are the alternates ways we can mitigate it.

Comment: You can't store into the same folder. Pig only accepts directories as paths for store, not files and HDFS is append/overwrite only. If you need the result as a single file you need a separate step to join them. To get a local version of the file you might want to look into hadoop fs -getmerge.

Comment: @user131990 : you need not merge the files (abc/100 ... abc/10000). you can read the content using a special character : A = LOAD 'abc/*/part*' ...